# Uploading Image from src of img tag to php

Tags: javascript, php

I just want to ask if there is a way to upload an image from `src` of `<img>` tag . The `src` of the `img` tag was not from the server and look like this one:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...52Eysdsadsa===" />
```

This was the product of the approach I learned from [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/) site.

Thank you in advance.

Let me know if you want me to explaine this dipper. Thank you

Comment: u need to use input FILE for uploading any kind of data..

Comment: You can send the src data via post to your server and write that into a file. No Form is needed for that only javascript and a receiving route on server

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can upload base64 encoded string(src part) to the server and save it as it is or convert it into an image and save it as a file.

**Uploading base64 encoded image:**

Get the src attribute of the image and post it to the server.

```
var base64image = $('#blah').attr('src');
```

**Converting base64 encoded string to image**

```
$img = $_POST['base64image'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = 'image.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

Or simply save the uploaded content into your database and later use the below code to render the image on your page:

```
echo '<img src="'. $img .'" />';
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the resulting file cannot be read by Paint. it says that "the file is not a valid bitmap file, or its format is not currently supported." my html and js looks like this https://jsfiddle.net/dr6vuofn/

Comment: Can you post the first part of your base 64 encoded data?

Comment: no. I'm calling this code via ajax and when I try to return the $data, the code calls the error callback with empty responseText. I tried to only returns a part of the $data using substr but still the same..