# Upload image from src attribute of img tag JQuery AJAX PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, upload

I wanted to know if there is a way to upload image to server from the `src` of the `img` tag. The `src` can be an absolute path or base64 encoded string depending on some conditions.

I tried a sample application using JQuery AJAX and PHP running in wamp server. In that I am creating a form with file upload control. And posting a FormData object of the uploaded image to server.
Reference: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/php-upload-image-tutorial-using-jquery-ajax/

Now I want to upload image from `src` instead of the image selected using file upload control.

Comment: "upload image from src " makes no senses to me. are you trying to download an image from another server?

Comment: In my page I have an image preview whose src may be an absolute path or base64 encoded string. And a button to upload image. So on this button's click action the image should be uploaded.

Comment: need to add the code for the preview to the question

Comment: <div class="previewContainer">
 <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="previewFrame"/>      
</div>

Comment: var iframe = document.getElementById('previewFrame');
var html = '<img class="previewImage" src=' + imgURL + '>';
var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
doc.body.innerHTML = html;

Comment: none of that gets a file from the users computer

Answer (score 1):

Yes , You can upload base64 encoded string(src part) to the server and save it as it is or convert it into an image and save it as a file.

[check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19048742/3553279)

Comment: What if src is an absolute path?

Comment: i think for absolute path it will work. For relative path like '/img/demo.png' needs to be converted to absolute path.

Comment: So any conversion to base64 is required for using the same code?